# How to split string into words that do not contain whitespaces in python?

Tags: python, string, list, whitespace

My string is:

```
"This     is a      string"
```

I want to turn it into a list:

```
["This", "is", "a", "string"]
```

I use the `split(" ")` method, but it adds whitespaces as list elements. Please help,

Best Regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> v="This is a  string"

>>> v.split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'string']
```

just use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 4):

It won't add whitespace as elements if you just use `.split()`, instead of `.split(' ')`

```
>>> "This     is a     string".split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'string']
```

Answer (score 3):

Like [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) say, don't pass an argument.

```
>>> "This is a string".split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'string']
```